# Motion Planning with base_local_planner

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a bit confused about how to use base_local_planner; I'm following  [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup#Robot_Setup) . Apologies if questions below seem silly; I'm a newcomer to ROS.

My robot configuration launch file looks like this:

`<launch>

 <node pkg="gazebo_plugins" type="hokuyo_node" name="hokuyo_node" output="screen">
    <param name="sensor_param" value="param_value" />
  </node>

 < uncommented for display ; odom is a c++ program I wrote to listen to odometry information -->
 <node pkg="learning_tf" type="odom" name="odom_node" output="screen">
    <param name="odom_param" value="param_value" />
  </node>


  <node pkg="tf" type="tf_echo" name="tf_listener" output="screen" args="/base_link /map">
  </node>

</launch>`

My move_base file is the same as erratic_navigation's move_base.launch.

Questions:

1. What are the sensor, odom and transform packages required for the robot configuration file? Are they listeners to the information published by move_base?

   The only odometry reading I get by looking at rostopic output is from erratic_odom. Is this enough?

   Is /base_link --> /map the right transformation for tf?

   What output should I expect after I run both launch files? Shouldn't I be getting a plan through which the robot moves, dumping output?

   Is hokuyo_node the right sensor?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10258/motion-planning-with-base_local_planner/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2011-06-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-06-19**:
Is there a particular reason for using the Erratic? Most Willow packages use the PR2 simulation and are better-supported than the Erratic packages. I'd start by playing around with the launch files recommended by Eitan below to get a feel for how everything plays together.

**Comment by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on 2011-06-16**:
I'm using the Erratic simulation.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-06-16**:
Do you have a real robot that you want to port to ROS? Or do you want to test the navigation stack using a simulated robot in Gazebo (e.g., the Erratic or PR2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you first tried the example launch files in the [navigation_stage](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation_stage) package. If you're just looking to run the navigation stack in simulation, that package is a good place to start.

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1